# Chinese Postman Problem: finding best connections between odd-degree nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am writing a Program, solving the [Chinese Postman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) (also known as route inspection problem) in an undirected draph and currently facing the problem to find the best additional edges to connect the nodes with odd degree, so I can compute an Eulerian circuit.

There might be (considering the size of the graph that wants to be solved) an enormous combination of edges which need to be computed and evaluated.

As an example there are the odd-degree nodes $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$. The best combinations could be:

1. $AB$, $CD$, $EF$, $GH$
2. $AC$, $BD$, $EH$, $FG$
3. $AD$, $BC$, $EG$, $FH$
4. $AE$ ....

where $AB$ means "edge between node $A$ and node $B$".

Therefore my question is: is there a known algorithm to solve that problem in a complexity better than pure brute force (computing and evaluating them all)?

€:After some research effort I found [this](http://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter6/6.4.4.html) article, speaking about the "Edmonds' minimum-length matching algorithm" but I cannot find any pseudo-code or learners-descriptions of this algorithm (or at least I do not recognize them, as Google offers a lot of hits an matching algorithms by J. Edmonds)

Comment: Wikipedia sais that there is an [$O(n^3)$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem#cite_note-1) for the Chinese Postman Problem.

Comment: I know, but I am still curious to know how to do that.

Comment: These lecture notes treat the Chinese Postman Problem: http://www.win.tue.nl/~nikhil/courses/2WO08/lec4.pdf

Comment: Sim, I am interested in your software since I am facing a mapping problem: http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13197/how-do-i-determine-the-shortest-path-that-traverses-all-streets-within-a-city Good luck with your project.
pm at pmbooks dot com

Comment: try the article I linked it describes a minimum length matching algorithm, but due to my lack of experience and the lack of pseudo-code I sadly was not able to implement it.

Comment: @Sim, has there been any progress that you'd like to share in answer format?

Comment: no, sadly not and as a solution was needed at a particular time i used brute force, no good solution therefore.

Comment: Please answer your question with the information collected and accept it to close the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As remarked in the comments, Wikipedia gives a [reduction from route inspection to minimum-weight matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem).  Vladimir Kolmogorov has published a [fast implementation](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html#BLOSSOM5) of the weighted version of Edmonds' blossom algorithm, in C++ [1].

[1] V. Kolmogorov, [Blossom V: A new implementation of a minimum cost perfect matching algorithm](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html). *Mathematical Programming Computation*, 1(1):43–67, 2009.

Comment: And let's not call it the "Chinese Postman Problem". The only link to China is that it was introduced by Mei-Ko Kwan and his nationality is irrelevant to the problem. Naming it "Chinese" suggests that the most significant thing about him is his ethnic origin. We don't, for example, refer to the well-known algorithm for computing shortest paths in graphs as "the Dutch algorithm" or, even worse, "the white man's algorithm". (Yes, I object to "Chinese remainder theorem" for the same reason but that horse bolted too long ago.)