# Enumerating all ways of pairing odd nodes

Tags: algorithms, enumeration

Can someone provide a brute force pseudocode for finding best connections between odd-degree nodes in the Chinese postman problem mentioned [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/chinese-postman-problem-finding-best-connections-between-odd-degree-nodes)?

For example, if the odd nodes are $B,C,D,E$, the program should output the three pairings

> BC,DE; BD,CE; BE,CD.

Comment: It seems that what you're really asking is: enumerate all partitions of $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ into pairs. This has nothing to do with the route inspection problem.

Comment: i mean how can i get unique combinations of pairs with a given odd-numbered vertices list. I think it is a stage to solve  route inspection problem , isn't it ?

Comment: Let me repeat the question. Will you be happy with an algorithm that enumerates all partitions of $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ into pairs?

Comment: yes i am asking for it . Can you please help about this if you have any idea?

Comment: thank you for classifying my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have much to do with the route inspection problem. You are looking for all perfect matchings of $K_{2n}$ (the complete graph on $2n$ vertices), or equivalently, for an algorithm that enumerates all partitions of $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ into pairs. A simple recursive approach is quite efficient:

> Input: A non-empty list $L$ of even size.
>
> Output: All possible partitions of $L$ into pairs.
>
> Algorithm:
>
> 1. If $L = \{a,b\}$, return $(a,b)$.
> 2. Otherwise, let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $L$. Go over all elements $b \in L \setminus \{a\}$. For each $b$, generate (recursively) all perfect matchings of $L \setminus \{a,b\}$, and add $(a,b)$ to all of them.

The number of perfect matchings is quite large:
$$
(2n-1) (2n-3) \cdots (1) = \frac{(2n!)}{2^nn!} \sim \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n} (2n/e)^{2n}}{2^n\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n} = \sqrt{2} \cdot (2n/e)^n.
$$

Comment: I am a bit confused with notation. can you please give more explanations for this solution.Btw i have found a solution for my problem , thanks to your classifying the problem ,in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568081/partitioning-a-sequence-into-sets-of-unique-pairs

Comment: You'd have to be more specific with what you don't understand.